# How to get indexes for values in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write a function that takes as argument 2d array. Each element of array has an Integer value.
As input i have a 2D array for example:

```
[1][1][2][2]
[2][1][2][2]
[3][3][3][3]
[22][.......
```

and as output I need to store indexes for each value :

```
value = 1 : [0,0] ; [0,1] ; [ 1,1]
value = 2 : [1,0] ; ....
value = 3 : [2,0] ; .......
value  = 22 : [.........
```

Size of array may be various, same as number of values. 
Is it somehow possible to save that data to vector, or any other data type so later i could read those values and their indexes?

Sorry if something is unclear, Its my 1st post here:)
Cheers

Edit:

so ok what I tried to do: I created a class Indexes

```
class Indexes
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and later i created a vector vect;
and i tried to add indexes to that vector. The problem was when i tried to keep values separated for examlpe

```
for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
     for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
        if(array[i][j].value = 1)
           Indexes ind(i,j);
       vect.push_back(ind);
     }
}
```

but all I could get is vector with only 1 values and its indexes stored;

Comment: Welcome to SO. Generally you need to state and post what you have tried to solve this problem. We won't just give out the answers. Once you do that we can help fix error and bugs you might have.

Comment: Provide the code describing your attempt to solve your problem, not only the input - output. Also write whether there are some constraints... is there any reason why you're not using `std::vector`s?

Comment: no it doesnt have to be vector, could use ANY type of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this index in a map of vectors of pairs, for example.

Here's some sample code:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> ElementIndex;
typedef std::vector<ElementIndex> IndexList;
typedef std::map<int, IndexList> ValuesIndexMap;
```

So `ValuesIndexMap` is a map from value to a vector of all indices in which this value is stored in, where an index (type `ElementIndex`) is a pair of ints - row and column.